# MySQL not returning the expected row output

Tags: mysql

I have been told I should be returning 10 rows of data, but my output isn't correct.
I am trying to get the number of comments and posts each user has made. I want the columns to be nickname, comments (containing total comments made) and posts(containing total posts made). I only want to show users who have made 1 or more comments or posts.

Current attempt:

```
SELECT postauthors.nickname, 
(select COUNT(postcomments.nickname) AS commentsMade 
 FROM postcomments 
 where 
 postcomments.nickname = postauthors.nickname) as Comments, 
(select COUNT(posts.postID) AS posts 
 FROM posts where posts.postID = postauthors.postID) as Posts
FROM postauthors
GROUP BY nickname
HAVING Comments >=1 OR Posts >=1;
```

Only getting as my return.

```
EBebe   2   1
joey    0   1
ricko   0   1
smithz  0   1
```

Table **postauthors**

```
CREATE TABLE postauthors ( nickname varchar(255) NOT NULL, 
                           postID int(11) NOT NULL, 
                           PRIMARY KEY (nickname,postID), 
                           KEY postIDPA (postID), 
                           CONSTRAINT nicknamePA FOREIGN KEY (nickname) REFERENCES users (nickname), 
                           CONSTRAINT postIDPA FOREIGN KEY (postID) REFERENCES posts (postID) ) 
ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `postauthors` VALUES ('EBebe',1),('joey',2),('ricko',3),('ricko',4),('smithz',5),('EBebe',6),('ricko',7);
```

Table **postcomments**

```
CREATE TABLE `postcomments (nickname varchar(255) NOT NULL,
                            postID int(11) NOT NULL,
                            datetime datetime NOT NULL,
                            content varchar(1000) NOT NULL,
                            PRIMARY KEY (nickname,postID,datetime),
                            KEY postIDPC (postID),
                            CONSTRAINT nicknamePC FOREIGN KEY (nickname) REFERENCES users (nickname),
                            CONSTRAINT postIDPC FOREIGN KEY (postID)
```

REFERENCES posts (postID)

```
INSERT INTO postcomments VALUES ('barbs',2,'2018-09-10 07:50:12','Working :('),('EBebe',2,'2018-09-10 10:02:20','Day off - so I\'ll probably sleep all day!'),('EBebe',5,'2018-09-11 16:06:02','Weightlifting!'),('GC',5,'2018-09-11 18:45:39','I like to walk with my dog'),('j75',2,'2018-09-10 07:51:00','Studying :('),('jerry',3,'2018-09-10 14:50:10','Food is the best!!!!!'),('kdog',6,'2018-09-12 09:10:14','The Bunnies!'),('niknik',6,'2018-09-12 08:30:30','Storm or Roosters');
```

Table **posts**

```
CREATE TABLE posts (postID int(11) NOT NULL,
                    datetime datetime NOT NULL,
                    content varchar(1000) NOT NULL,
                    PRIMARY KEY (postID);

INSERT INTO posts VALUES (1,'2018-09-10 00:01:30','Hi, nice to meet everyone!'),(2,'2018-09-10 07:45:00','What is everyone doing today?'),(3,'2018-09-10 13:20:49','How amazing is food!!! Had the best lunch!'),(4,'2018-09-11 09:03:11','Feeling better today than yesterday'),(5,'2018-09-11 14:12:23','How do you like to get exercise?'),(6,'2018-09-11 23:45:30','Who do you think will win the NRL grand final?'),(7,'2018-09-12 07:02:12','Today was a great day :)');
```

I am expecting 10 rows of text to be returned, as in 10 names with numbers in the columns can have a NULL in one, but not both

Comment: Please share your sample table structure with minimal, relevant data. Also add expected output as per your sample data, and what you are currently getting based on your current attempt.

Comment: Please click on [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52678300/edit) link and update all these details in the question itself.

Comment: Or, you can create a [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/) or [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com) and update your question with the link.

Comment: Madhur is that what you were after?

Comment: Amanda: I have formatted on of your create table statements, as an example. Kindly format the rest of them for ease of readability

Comment: I have also tried this, but I have duplicates in my table that I cannot have:
    SELECT postauthors.nickname, count(posts.datetime) AS postsWritten, null 
    as commentsMade
    FROM postauthors, posts
    WHERE postauthors.postID = posts.postID
    GROUP BY nickname
    UNION 
    SELECT postcomments.nickname,null as postsWritten, 
    count(postcomments.content) AS commentsMade
    FROM postcomments
    GROUP BY nickname;

Comment: Amanda- I have edited. Please check it. Should be helpful for you, for next time when you post a new question.

Comment: You cannot get 10 rows; as per your sample data, you have only 7 nicknames, out of which 3 are duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

The relation between Post and Postauthors are going in the wrong direction.
Table Post should have a foreign key added like nickname.

One author should be able to post more than once.

Your where clause does not reference the correct tables.

Then the statement should look like this:

```
SELECT postauthors.nickname, 
(select COUNT(*) FROM postcomments where nickname = postauthors.nickname) as Comments, 
(select COUNT(*) FROM posts where nickname = postauthors.nickname) as Posts 
FROM postauthors GROUP BY nickname
HAVING  
(select COUNT(*) FROM postcomments  where nickname = postauthors.nickname) >=1 OR 
(select COUNT(*) FROM posts where nickname = postauthors.nickname) >=1;
```

Comment: Thanks Allan. I gave that a go, but it is throwing an error at me.
Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'healthconnect.postauthors.postID' in 'where clause'

Comment: Strange, I did not use the word healthconnect in my code?

Comment: I thought the same thing. the main database in its entirety is called healthconnent

Comment: PostID should not be in the table postauthors. Instead you should have a foreign key in posts like nickname.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot change the table columns. the structure needs to remain the same

Comment: The edited version returns 7 in all of the post column entries

Comment: There are only 7 records in postauthors. As this is the only table in the from clause you will only get 7 records.